# Replace Incomplete Bracket with Gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I want to do a simple replace in R for the following column:

```
df

                                                                        Songs
1                                                      Saga (Skit) [feat. RZA
2                                                                     Revenge
3                                                           Whatever You Want
4                                                               What About Us
5                                                              But We Lost It
6                                                                     Barbies
```

I want to do two different replacements:

1) Replace "[" with blank

2) Replace "]" with blank

Need to do this separately though because some of my values only has 1 on the brackets like the first value in the `Songs` column.

```
df[,1]<-gsub("[","",df[,1])
```

Error:

```
Error in gsub("[", "", newdf2[, 1]) : 
  invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''
```

How do I go about going around this invalid regular expression error?

Thanks!

Comment: @Henrik apologies, didn't see the other question. Bryan Goggin and akrun were helpful though in giving a different way of solving it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you have to double escape things in R. This should work to do both the replacements in one go.

```
gsub("\\[|\\]", "", df$Songs)
```

Comment: Your solution looks similar to mine

Comment: It is almost as if there is a correct way to do it...

Answer (score 2):

The `[` is a metacharacter, so it needs to be escaped

```
gsub("\\[|\\]", "", df$Songs)
```

Or other way is

```
gsub("[][]", "", df$Songs)
```